# Load Clicked Id's Website in iframe on Click for Website in Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Current Website:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51T2e.jpg)

I have a website that is generated by a for loop from a call to my database using php & mysql. I have an id, names, company website, address and image. It currently displays the name, description, and image all displayed in stacked square boxes.

On click of the box, I'm trying to load an iframe of the company website that then overlays the box. I have been able to get all of the website iframes to load when I load the site, but if there are more than 5-6 rows of data, the site loads very slow because it's loading ~7 websites.

I've spent most of the day looking through jquery and iframe questions but still have not been able to get my iframes to load on click individually when you click on the box. my intention is to have the user click on the description/company box not the iframe. This will then load the iframe and have it appear over the company box where it fills/hides the content in the box completely overlaying the box content.

How do you load a website onclick that is opened within an iframe without loading all of the iframes inside a dynamically generated page.

```
    <?php require_once('include/header.php')?>
    <? require('include/navigation.php')    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Coworking Spaces</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/mystyles'); ?>">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(function(){
        $("iframe").each(function(){
            this.tmp = this.src;
            this.src = "";
        })
        .parent(".website")
        .click(function(){
            var frame = $(this).children("iframe")[0];
            console.log(frame);        frame.src = frame.tmp;
        });
    });
        </script>
    </script>
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id='city_header'>
            <div id='city_search'>
                <h1>
                    Kansas City
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
                    <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($cospaces); ++$i){?>
                    <div class="company_box" style ="background-image: url(<?php echo($cospaces[$i]['image'])?>);">

                    <div class="name_box">
                        <h3 class="space_name"><?php echo($cospaces[$i]['name'])?></h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="description">
                        <p><?php echo($cospaces[$i]['description']) ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- iframe wanting to load -->
                    <iframe id = "website" data-src="<?php echo($cospaces[$i]['website'])?>" width="200" height="200" style="background:#ffffff"></iframe>

            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

TESTED Suggested implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('iframe').bind('load', function() {
           var childFrame = $(this).contents().find('iframe');
           var childElement = childFrame.contents().find('body');
           var src =  $(this).attr('data-src');
           childElement.on('click', function() {
              childFrame.attr('src', src);
           });
        });
    });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe data-src="https://jsfiddle.net" srcdoc="<iframe id='hi' srcdoc='<body>Click me</body>'></iframe>">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats the actual question?

Comment: How do you load a website onclick that is opened within an iframe without loading all of the iframes inside a dynamically generated page. (I updated question with this as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing where `this.src` is defined within the PHP generated iframes for your initial `.each` function call.

I am also unsure why you are calling `.parent('.website')`, since that would traverse upward looking for a wrapping element with `class="website"`, where the PHP generated iframes would have no parent other than the div with `id="body"`. 
e.g your code is looking for:

```
<div class="website">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

One thing to keep in mind when working with iFrames, is that their content is not available on DOMReady, so you must attach a load listener to each iFrame you want to modify the contents of.

If I understand you correctly, you simply want the `src` of the iframe to load when a user clicks the iframe. Have you tried something like

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $('iframe').on('click', function(e) {
      var frame = $(this);
      frame.attr('src', frame.attr('data-src'));
      frame.off('click'); //remove on-click event to prevent reloading on click
   });
});
```

The iFrame target is very small, and would only trigger the click event when clicking the outer-border of the iFrame and not its content body. iFrames do not act like `<div>` elements or other block elements in regards to DOM Events, and mileage will vary on what you can do per browser and per version.

Unless you are attempting to find iframes and change their source within the Coworking Spaces created iframes, which is not possible using Javascript unless the child iframes reside on the same domain. See: [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Otherwise you can do something similar to

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('iframe').bind('load', function() {
       var childFrame = $(this).contents().find('iframe');
       var childElement = childFrame.contents().find('body');
       var src =  $(this).attr('data-src');
       childElement.on('click', function() {
          childFrame.attr('src', src);
       });
    });
});
```

This will tell your script to wait for each master iframe to load, find its child iframe, attach an onclick event to the child iframe body to set the source to the master iframes `data-src`

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Laomfx7g/

I use the `srcdoc` attribute to load static HTML into the iFrame to demonstrate binding to same-origin content, since I would not be able to edit the source content of an external website from jsfiddle.

Lastly element id's (specifically `<iframe id="website"` in your for loop) are expected to be unique, and will function wildly different in varying browsers. Some will only affect the first element with the specified id, others will affect the last, where a few will read all of the specified ids, which may or may not be intended.

**EDIT - from comment clarification**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.description').on('click', function() {
       var frame = $(this).next('iframe');
       frame.attr('src', frame.attr('data-src'));
       $(this).off('click'); //remove click event
    });
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2x0yfpts/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. It helped me understand the DOM a little better. The reason for parent was that was basically my final attempt of about 20 different stack overflow posts. When I tried to implement your solution, I could not get it to work. I even created a brand new test file with just your code and it still did'nt work.

Comment: Also to clarify, my intention is to have the user click on the description/company box not the iframe. This will then load the iframe and have it appear over the company box where it fills the box completely overlaying the box content in the website example.

Comment: Where is the description/company box located. I presume you mean clicking on `<div id="body"><div class="description">` that is not inside of an iframe? If this is the case option 1 should be used, binding `.on('click')` to the description. I'll update my answer

Comment: The company box is the background image div that has description, name and website iframe inside of it.

Comment: @JustinChristian updated the answer. That should give you an idea on how to select the desired element to click with jQuery and select any preceding elements. Be sure to look at the jQuery reference for Dom Traversing using `next`, `nextAll`, `prev`, `prevAll`, `find`, `parent`, `parents` (yes different as it breaks upward until it finds the selector), etc https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: Also the website MUST be on the same domain. For example change the `data-src` attribute in my jsfiddle example from `jsfiddle.net` to  `google.com` or `stackoverflow.com` and it will fail to load without the iframe source domain trusting your domain for the request. EG: `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Comment: Thanks for all your help! It looks like I cant use data-src and will just have to use src and load all the pages at once and use a show/hide toggle. Not a problem, just not as good UX, but I'm very glad after almost 2-days to have figured this out. I'd give you give you the internet if I could for how much you helped me out on this. Thanks!